# Binding multiple models Cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-1.3, cakephp-model

I am trying to bind 3 models in cakephp.The relation is as follows

> Member hasMany Member_Organaization  Member_Organisations belongs to
>   Organaization

i try to use

> $this->Member->find('all',conditions)

it just show me only data upto hasMany association.
I understand that the Member model is not related directly to the organization one.
but how can we do it?
My code is as follows:

```
$this->Member->bindModel(
               array(
                 'hasMany'=>array(
                     'NpoMember' =>array(
                      'className' => 'NpoMember',
                      'foreignKey' => 'member_id',
                      'conditions' => array('NpoMember.status' => 'Active'),
                  )         
               )
            )
        ); 
        $this->NpoMember->bindModel(
               array(
                 'belongsTo'=>array(
                     'Npo'=>array(
                      'className' => 'Npo',
                      'foreignKey' => 'npo_id',
                      'conditions' => array('Npo.status' => 'Active')
                    )        
               )
            )
        ); 
        $userData  = $this->Member->find('first',array('conditions'=>array('Member.email'=>$userEmail,'Member.password'=>$passWord,'Member.status'=>'Active')));
```

I found this site to be very helpful.
Thanks and Regards
Himanshu Sharma

Comment: Try recursive value 2 before your query `$this->Member->recursive = 2;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `recursive` the cakephp functionality for this type of purpose.

In your controller: `$this->Member->recursive = 2;` use this before your find query.

Refrence : `http://book.cakephp.org/view/1063/recursive`