# CakePHP no data from related model

Tags: model, relationship, cakephp-2.1

i have 2 models related to each other.

```
class AccountModel extends AppModel {

    public $name = 'Account';
    public $belongsTo = array(
        'User' => array(
            'className' => 'User',
            'foreignKey'   => 'user_id',

        ),
    );
}

class UserModel extends AppModel {

    public $name = 'User';
    public $hasMany = array(
        'Account' => array(
            'className' => 'Account',
            'foreignKey'   => 'user_id',

        ),
    );

}
```

tables:
accounts
-id
-user_id
-other fields...

users
-id
-other fields...

requesting data from one model only returns data of this, but no related data.
i want to request model User with id and returning all User-data and related Account-data.
same with requesting Account-model with one param, not account_id or user_id, and returning all Account-data and related User-data.

```
$User = $this->Account->findByField($param);
```

only returns array('Account' => array(...)) and

```
$User = $this->User->findById($id);
```

only returns array('User' => array(...)) but no request returns array('User' => array(...), 'Account' => array(..))

How will i get all related data?

Greetings
m.

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7846230/binding-multiple-models-cakephp/7846332#7846332

Comment: $this->Account->recursive = 2; has no effect, same with $this->Account->find('first', array('conditions' => array('field' => $param), 'recursive' => 2));

Comment: Go [here](http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/en/The-Manual/Developing-with-CakePHP/Models.html) and search `saveAll($data)`. That is something about **For saving a record along with its related records** which is just what you want. Good Luck!

Comment: which is just what i want? i want to find, not to save. :/

Comment: Install CakePHP's debug kit toolbar (https://github.com/cakephp/debug_kit) and take a look at the SQL being generated for your query.

Comment: cake works only with model database, not with related databases. $this->User->find or save only act with users table, not with related accounts table

Answer (score 0):

`FindBy{fieldname}` does not allow for the recursive option ( as defined in the cakephp documentation `findBy<fieldName>(string $value[, mixed $fields[, mixed $order]]);` ).

In order to get recursive data by relationship, you should use the find method.

```
$userData = $this->User->find('first', array(
    'conditions' => array('id' => $userId),
    'recursive' => 1,
));
```

If no data is returned, check the following:
- is there a valid userId being passed?
- is there data in both tables for the given userId?
- are the models loaded correctly where you are trying to run the Find query?